# How do I recreate this tree swaying animation?

Tags: unity

I really like this effect that I saw in a kid's mobile game. https://gfycat.com/thunderousimpishblacknorwegianelkhound I'm trying to create this effect in my game. The trees seem to deform with every slight movement/swipe in the game, pulling more to the right or left depending on the velocity of the swipe, I think? Here's what I've tried:

- Rigging three bones through the trees, and then animating it by
  rotating the bones. But this doesn't solve the problem of how it's
  deforming literally everything in the rig (unless there are bones
  through everything), and also it seems like the top of the trees are
  being pulled in either direction.
- Also I can't easily adjust the rotation angle according to velocity
  at runtime, unless I use curves -- but this seems over the top and I
  doubt it's that?
- Looking up Shaders that could deform bodies like this, but couldn't
  find anything like it.
- Looking at Sprite Shape, but that seems to be for tiled objects, not
  something like this.

How would you approach this problem? Is there something obvious that I am missing here?

Comment: This appears to be yet another duplicate of [a recently asked question that was deleted by its author](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/201707/39518). When you want to amend a question, the correct course of action is to click the "Edit" link to modify it in-place. Deleting and re-posting can look like an attempt to evade moderation, and can cause automated scripts to apply restrictions to your account. If you accidentally created two different user accounts, [follow the steps here to merge them](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Comment: It's also not clear to me what aspect of this effect you believe would be difficult to accomplish with bones. How did the results you get from using a skinned sprite differ from what you want?